# PHP : url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to know how to page url without .php extension

for ex here is my website :

http://mywebsite.com/ now from the home page whenever i click on any gallery it will goes to the page gallery.php with querystring of galleryID for ex

http://mywebsite.com/gallery.php?id=29

So instead of this gallery.php?id=29 I want to make the url something related to the page title

http://mywebsite.com/9-WEDDING-GIFT-IDEAS

Thanks in advance

Comment: How will id become title in URL?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a PHP framework once you start going down this path, that gives your application/site a structure, and the ability to setup routes (paths) like you're requesting.

I'm a fan of [Laravel](http://laravel.com), this allows you to use http://example.com/index.php/friendly-url/goes-here if you haven't setup Apache (the web server) to remove them.

You can remove the index.php/ part and just have http://example.com/friendly-url/goes-here by using the Apache mod_rewrite which Laravel includes for you. Check out [the documentation under Pretty URLs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi i have php site in windows hosting, so i have to deal with web.config file instead of .htaccess

Comment: What version of Windows and IIS? Many .htaccess rules are fairly easy to translate to URLRewrite in IIS 7/7.5

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.  If you don't have a ton of URLs, you can add them in to your '.htaccess' file manually.

```
RewriteEngine On

# MANUAL
RewriteRule ^9-WEDDING-GIFT-IDEAS/?$ gallery.php?id=29 [L]
RewriteRule ^MOST-BEAUTIFUL-WEDDING-LOCATIONS/?$ gallery.php?id=30 [L]
# ...
```

Otherwise, you can have 'gallery.php' handle looking up which article to display based on the title.  So if it receives a title of '9-WEDDING-GIFT-IDEAS', then it can look up that title in the database and fetch the article for that title.  Here, the article title will be passed as the 'id' parameter to 'gallery.php'.

```
RewriteEngine On

# PARSING HANDLED IN gallery.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gallery.php?id=$1 [L]
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
// gallery.php

$article_title = $_GET['id'];

// ...
// DO A DB LOOKUP TO GET THE ARTICLE ID WHERE TITLE = '$article_title'
// OR JUST GET THE ARTICLE BASED ON THE TITLE INSTEAD
```

Comment: Hi i have one gallery.php and i am passing with query string using the id as queryString. Can you give me more info about how to implement using the gallery title ?

Comment: Yeah, sure thing.  Once you are successfully passing the name to `gallery.php` through `id=$1`, then in `gallery.php`, you can access the page name via `$_GET['id']`.  Then, just do a database lookup on the article where the title equals what was matched (9-WEDDING-GIFT-IDEAS, for example).  I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: But friend if i pass from index.php to gallery it will show the url like gallery.php?id-10 so how the url will look different ?

Comment: Dipa, have you actually tried this?  I copy/pasted the code exactly as I have it now in the answer and for both `.htaccess` and `gallery.php` and it worked exactly as it should.  The only thing I added was to print out the article title in gallery.  `print "Article Title: ".$article_title;`  Then I went to it in my browser `http://YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE.com/9-WEDDING-GIFT-IDEAS` and now I get `Article Title: 9-WEDDING-GIFT-IDEAS`, and the URL does not change to `gallery.php`.

Comment: No worries now, i found very good article on it and solved my problem now all issues are solved ! but thanks for your help