# IIS 8 URL rewrite: possible to return different results in one rule?

Tags: php, regex, iis, url-rewriting

Windows Server 2012, IIS 8; running a combination of Classic ASP and PHP.

I think I already know the answer to this one, but just in case I'm not as smart as I think I am...

I've got a car dealership client who has created a separate page for every make/model combination they offer, ~48 pages. They would like each one pointed to with a friendly URL, e.g.

```
theirSite.com/shop-chevrolet-camaro-inventory
```

=

```
index.php?p=123.
```

This means creating 48 separate rewrite rules, and while there's nothing inherently wrong with that, it bugs me to death. Had they consulted me, first, I would have advised them to create each of these as a template file, and I would have written a program to load them dynamically, using one page and one rewrite rule.

So, it is possible for the rewrite rule to somehow dictate a piece of the rewrite result? Taking

```
/shop-chevrolet-camaro
```

where camaro translates to page 123; corvette translates to page 124; cruze translates to 125; and so on? For SEO purposes, I can't point to an intermediate page and introduce a redirect, we have to hit the destination page directly as a rewrite.

Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably still can go with your idea here of just one page and one .htaccess redirect; Just a little different approach.

You can probably use `include` to bring their data from one of the 48 pages and display it on your "master" page.  Now, to figure out which page to pull in, I wrote an answer to a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714410/3293987

Hopefully this helps you.  The basic premise is to take the "friendly" name (as it is appearing in the `.htaccess` and pass that to the script instead of the id number.  Then, in your script, you'd do a lookup by the "friendly" name instead of the id.  Then you can programmatically find which page needs loaded and use PHP's `include` to pull in the data.

As far as your concern of having an intermediate page for the redirect, you should not need to do a redirect with this solution; You can just load the data from the existing "peripheral" page on to the "master" page.

I hope that answer helps you.